# Rigidbody bouncing on a gameobject indefinitely

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a unity 2D game and following is the issue I am currently facing. I have a platform gameobject which can be either static or moving (vertically or horizontally). When the platform moves vertically downward, any rigidbody placed on the said platform starts bouncing indefinitely. My platform is not a rigidbody, it only has a collider.

What might be the problem and the best way to fix it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `rigidbody.isKinematic = true;`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you move the platform down, the rigidbody has some space to fall, it falls down, bounces, and when it returns back down from the bounce, the platform has moved a bit more, adding to the distance left to fall.

If the rigidbodies will always stay on the platform, a solution could be creating an empty gameobject to be the parent of both the platform and the rigidbodies, and then moving that gameobject, so the rigidbodies move together with the platofrm.

If you don't know whether the rigidbodies would be on the platform or not, you could, when moving the platform, check which rigidbodies are on it, and just move those.